# Jquery count down date

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Does anyone know how i can use Jquery to update the content in the td id jailtimer.
i need it to countdown until it hits 0

example

00:00:02

00:00:01

00:00:00 Done

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jail ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
$jail_oname = htmlspecialchars($row->username);
$jail_otimeleft = htmlspecialchars($row->time_left);
$oleft = $jail_otimeleft - time();
if ($oleft < '0'){
$sql = "DELETE FROM jail WHERE username='".$jail_oname."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="jailtimer"><?php echo date( "00:i:s", $jail_otimeleft - time() ); ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Heres a code that will put data into the mysql table

```
<?
if ($_POST['Failcaptcha']){
    $jailtime = 1500;
        $Time_Jail=time()+ $jailtime;
    echo "<p id=\"MyStatus\">You clicked the wrong button you goto jail for 25 Minutes!</p>";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `jail` ( `id` , `username` , `time_left` , `reason` , `bust_able` )
    VALUES ('', '$username', '$Time_Jail', 'Failed captcha', '1')");
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this, but are you actually *tracking* each tick (of whatever length) in the table? Why not get a start time, and then per view just show how much time is left between now that start time? Your code below seems to suggest this is how you're doing it, but your column name `time_left` is not properly descriptive then of what it references.

Comment: ok let me show u how i insert data into that table, im using this for a text game im making and it puts them in jail for 25 minutes and when the time runs out they are out, the code is working good i just want to use jquery so they can see how much time they have left to wait live.

Comment: Ok, I see; you're storing `time_released`. I'm not a fan of the syntax. If you want to *asynchronously* update that field, use http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ and get the difference between `time_released` and `time()` and (on the server) return the time to your page.

Comment: Not sure how i would use that, And how come ur not a fan of this method. how would u do it?

Comment: I'm not a fan of syntax of `time_left` the way it's being used, I'd probably call it `time_released` or `release_time`. Try a [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Comment: also this code is in a while loop and there can be many results, and i would need it to count down on every result.

Comment: I agree - there's no need to use "time_left" if you already have "Time_Jail", as you can always calculate "time_left" as `Time_Jail - time()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm2aY/1/) showing how to make clocks running forward or backward in jquery quite easily. 
Enjoy.

the HTML code is :

```
<div class="time"></div>
<div class="backtime"></div>
```

This is the JS code :

```
$(function(){
    var $currentDate = new Date().getTime();
    setInterval(function(){
         $(".time").text(new Date());
        console.log(new Date().setTime($currentDate));
         $currentDate = $currentDate - 1000;
        $(".backtime").text(new Date($currentDate) );        
    },1000);
});​
```

This will display the remaining time on GUI but will not update the DB. 
I assume you don't want to do the round-trip of going to the server every second. 
I suggest you get rid of the column "time_left" and  just use "release_date" which means "when will they be released?"

Let me know if more explanations required.

Comment: ugh i cant get it to work, im newer to javascript how would u get this function to load on start or give the function a name to call it from somewhere else

Comment: the syntax `$(function(){ ... })` tells JQuery to run this as the page loads. You don't need a function to call it.. When you say "i can't get it to work" - do you mean on "fiddle" or locally? because on fiddle you need to click "run" and locally you have to make sure jquery is imported and the page doesn't have any errors. You can check out [my WIKI page for web developers tools](http://wiki.mograbi.info/developers-tools-for-web-development) it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: If this HTML snippet is injected to the HTML with an Ajax request, you need to remove the `$(function(){ ... })` as the page will not generate a "on-load" event.